# how do I pop a view on a UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a screen tutorial for my app. I have a `UIPageViewController` setup to manage 3 View Controllers. Once you get to the last view on the tutorial you press a "done" button and the tutorial is supposed to go away.

I can't seem to find a way to pop/dismiss the tutorial. I have tried the following:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

The View Controllers being managed are subviews of `UIViewController` if that's of any help.

[image]

EDIT
This is how I set up the views:
In my UIPageViewController I have the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[self.pageController setViewControllers:@[tutorialPages[0]]
                              direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                               animated:NO
                             completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
[[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

}

```
- (void)setupContentViews{
ScreenTutorial_1ViewController *screenTutorial1 = [[ScreenTutorial_1ViewController    alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenTutorial_1ViewController" bundle:nil];
ScreenTutorial_2ViewController *screenTutorial2 = [[ScreenTutorial_2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenTutorial_2ViewController" bundle:nil];
ScreenTutorial_3ViewController *screenTutorial3 = [[ScreenTutorial_3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenTutorial_3ViewController" bundle:nil];
tutorialPages = @[screenTutorial1, screenTutorial2, screenTutorial3];
NSLog(@"tutorPages = %@", tutorialPages);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First, I strongly recommend you using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@YES forKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"];
```

Secondly, how are you presenting your PageViewController? In order to dismiss it like you have, you need to use (from a UIViewController):

```
[self presentViewController:tutorial animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Where *tutorial* is your Tutorial View controller. This will slide it up across the screen (or  you can not animate it), and then you can dismiss it like you have.

Comment: Wayfarer, please see the EDIT I made on my original post. I am using a  UIPageViewController.

Comment: Wayfarer, I will use your suggestion regarding passing a string to NSUserDefaults. Also thanks for helping me understand more about how dismissing views work. I didn't know that I needed to dismiss a view the same way I presented it. It makes sense though. I did solve the issue. See answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Wild shot in the dark here, but I think you could reach your `UIPageVieWController` by calling `self.parentViewController` in your child controllers.

You could then either dismiss it (if it's modally presented) or pop it.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I had 2 views in a xib file and the IBAction was connected to the wrong one. I've been copying and pasting buttons, labels...etc. On one of those pastes, I must have copied the pasted the entire view. I deleted it and used the following command which did dismiss the View:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```